# grep file and match strings in a line

Tags: unix, grep

I have below lines in my file. I wanted to grep all the lines in my log file where baseFileName is not equal to my file name. In the below case It should print line 1 because TEST boo.docx is not equal to Test foo-boo.docx.

```
2017-06-19 21:54:11,773 mimeType=docx,baseFileName=TEST boo.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-ba71-e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,Test foo-boo.docx    [source:MessageConsumer]

2017-06-19 21:54:11,774 mimeType=docx,baseFileName=TEST foo.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-ba71-e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,Test foo.docx    [source:MessageConsumer]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my file name" ?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is question has a unix-tag:

```
grep -P "baseFileName=([^,]+),.*,\1" test.txt
```

Explanation:

```
baseFileName=([^,]+)       # first pair of parentheses gives you baseFilename                   
,.*,                       # read ',' followed by anything, followed by ','
\1                         # backreference to baseFilename
```

Testing:

```
$ cat test.txt
2017-06-19 21:54:11,773 mimeType=docx,baseFileName=TEST 
boo.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-ba71-
e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,Test foo-boo.docx    
[source:MessageConsumer]

2017-06-19 21:54:11,774 mimeType=docx,baseFileName=TEST 
foo.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-ba71-
e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,TEST foo.docx    
[source:MessageConsumer]
2017-06-19 21:54:11,774 
mimeType=docx,baseFileName=aaa.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-
ba71-e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,aaa.docx    
[source:MessageConsumer]

$ grep -P "baseFileName=([^,]+),.*,\1" test.txt
2017-06-19 21:54:11,774 mimeType=docx,baseFileName=TEST 
foo.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-ba71-
e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,TEST foo.docx    
[source:MessageConsumer]
2017-06-19 21:54:11,774 
mimeType=docx,baseFileName=aaa.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-
ba71-e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589,aaa.docx    
[source:MessageConsumer]
```

Comment: Thanks.I  have a space `2017-06-19 21:54:11,773 mimeType=docx,baseFileName=TEST boo.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-ba71-e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589, 
 Test foo-boo.docx    [source:MessageConsumer]`

Comment: In your example filenames are different. One contains all capital letters, the other only starts with a capital.

Comment: That's right  the  example you mentioned  in cat  is  perfect  but only thing I have a space in my logs.  `mimeType=docx,baseFileName=aaa.docx,fileNamePrefix=7ff852cb-b1db-49d3-
ba71-e151dbc1f41e,doEncrypt=true,decryptedFileSize=125589, aaa.docx    
[source:MessageConsumer]` .Please not space before  aaa.docx

Comment: $ grep -P "baseFileName=([^,]+),.*,\s\1" test.txt

Comment: thanks for that that works.But I want to  grep  the names which are not matching.I tried grep -P -v but it prints lot of other invalid lines

Comment: Here's your problem. Negating the regex with -v doesn't work because it produces every line that doesn't match, so even a line "This is rubbish" passes. A negative lookahead would solve this, but apparently that doesn't work using grep. (??) What you could do is do a "grep 'basefileName" test.txt and pipe that into 'grep -v -P "baseFileName=([^,]+),.*,\s\1"'